# Lp space is always separable?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Can anyone give me a counterexample?

Comment: This seems like an example of the level of questions that deserve to be answered and then closed.

Comment: $L^\infty$ is normally not separable. (Hint: Take the integers with counting measure.)

Comment: Is there any reason for this question to remain open?  It seems to be undergraduate level.

Comment: You might find more explanation on http://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4):

How about an uncountable discrete measure space in which each point has measure one.